# Group Header Birt Reporting

Tags: reporting, birt

I have 20 columns in my group header. When I generate report I can see all the 20 columns appear in one row and they are all squeezed(truncated). 
How can I avoid these truncation and split my group header into multiple group header rows, so that they don't truncate when generated a report.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest better to add css file to your report . So there is a chance of avoiding truncation and for more accurate answer provide me with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rework the group header layout yourself. Remember you can use multiple groups and you can also use multiple header rows for a single group header...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you please give some reference links so that I can follow those.